# Unable to get curl_init() to work with dynamically generated URLs

Tags: php, curl

I am writing a PHP script to retrieve an audio file off a remote website. The script is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once 'table_access/simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php';
function getsound($wrd){
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/' . rawurlencode($wrd));
    $colentry = $html->find('div.source');
    if($colentry != null){
        $ahref = $colentry[0]->find('a.audio-start');
        $audiolink = trim($ahref[0]->getAttribute('href'));

        $testval = 'http://audio1.spanishdict.com/audio?lang=es&text=hombre&key=84be08a91b32dc61e45f8f78970b206b';
        echo '<p> T: ' . $testval . '</p>';
        echo '<p> A: ' . $audiolink . '</p>';
        // $testval = $audiolink;
        $ch = curl_init($audiolink);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($status == 200) { file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/audiotest.mp3', $output); }
        else { echo $status; }

        return($audiolink);
    }
}

echo '<p>' . getsound('hombre') . '</p>';
?>
```

I am using the [simple html DOM script](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) to scrape the remotely accessed page. For testing purposes, I have the URL assigned to two different variables:

- **$audiolink:** This one is being generated dynamically off the page being scraped.
- **$testval:** This one is a non-dynamic variable with a sample URL assigned to it manually.

The test case I am using returns the exact same values for either variables as is evident in the output of the **echo()** commands. However, the target file is downloading only if I pass **$testval** (the hard-coded value) to the **curl_init()** function. If I pass it **$audiolink** (the dynamically generated value), the script runs without any error but fails to download the file. The values in either variables in my test run, I repeat, are identical.

Is there anything I am overlooking? As stated above, the script isn't throwing any error when being passed **$audiolink**; the *error.log* file is empty.

**Update:** Just **echo()**'ed the status code and turns out it's 400 when the I use **$audiolink** and 200 when I use **$testval**.

Comment: I would if I could. As I've stated in the question, there's no error being thrown by the script. The *error.log* file is empty.

Comment: 400 is a bad request, I assume that the $audiolink is not valid. Can you post the content of $audiolink?

Comment: The values in both $audiolink and $testval are exactly the same and that's what's got me stumped. The only difference is that while $audiolink is being assigned a URL dynamically, $testval is assigned a static value. You can view the output of this code at: http://www.peppyburro.com/sandboxassets/engines/pronunciation1.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe it's an encoding issue:

```
http://audio1.spanishdict.com/audio?lang=es&text=hombre&key=84be08a91b32dc61e45f8f78970b206b
```

vs.

```
http://audio1.spanishdict.com/audio?lang=es&amp;text=hombre&amp;key=84be08a91b32dc61e45f8f78970b206b
```

try to encode the & and ? correctly, maybe [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) will help

Comment: When I wrap the value assigned to `$audiolink` in htmlspecialchars_decode() the file downloads :)

Comment: Perfect! It worked! What a stupid error, indeed. Thanks a ton. :)